# How can I include a number when targeting JSON data using fetch?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

**This has been solved, thanks!**

The data I need is in JSON format. I have used fetch to get the JSON data and parse it. However, when targeting the right data the data I need is wrapped in a 0. When I go to target this in JavaScript, it turns red with any number and returns "undefined" in the console.

How can I target this array of data in JSON even though it is wrapped in a zero? Is there some sort of JavaScript workaround? Seems like something that would be fairly simple I'm just not sure how to do it.

```
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.feed.entry.0)
  })
```

[image: JSON Data wrapped in 0 array]

[image]

Comment: it's an array. Get it by `data.feed.entry[0]`

Comment: 0 is index. You can select indexes with [index]. data.feed.entry[0]

Comment: Perfect, that's what it was! Thank you!